# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception in for loop when trying to parse data

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a code for a requirement. If for example I have this test data:

```
multiple variable:
3
Context Change (next in array)
1
Context Change (next in array)
2

Repeat variable:
TESTA
Context change (next in array)
TESTB
Context change (next in array)
TESTC
```

**Code:**
I've tried using `j` as the array. Both `i` and `j` are failing since if for example `i` is 3 in the 1st array, then `multiple[i]` will be `multiple[3]` which is out of bounds already.

```
for(int j=0; j <= multiple.length - 1; j++) {
   for(int i=0; i < Integer.parseInt(multiple[i]); i++) {
      result.addValue(Repeat[i]);
   }
}
```

Output should be this one:

```
TESTA
TESTA
TESTA
Context change (next in array)
TESTB
Context change (next in array)
TESTC
TESTC
```

Comment: Typo - shouldn't `Integer.parseInt(multiple[i])` be `Integer.parseInt(multiple[j])`?

Comment: Thank you Sir Eran. I actually tried that already.  Output is not as intended

Comment: If that doesn't solve your problem, how come you accepted an answer that suggests the exact same thing?

Comment: Sorry Sir. Actually it's not yet solved. I want to mark your answer is the answer but i can't find it

Comment: I did not post an answer. I only commented. And if your problem is not solved, you shouldn't mark any answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only thing wrong about your code with a first look:

```
for(int j = 0; j <= multiple.length - 1; j++) {
   for(int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(multiple[j]); i++) {
      result.addValue(Repeat[i]);
   }
}
```

You should be using **`multiple[j]`** instead of **`multiple[i]`** since your are looping in that loop. Other thing is why are you doing **`multiple.length - 1`**? Also please clarify what you want to do because your answer doesn't make that much sense, at least to me. **What are you trying to do?** If this helps, than great! Otherwise **clarify** the problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Giorgos. Unfortunately, instead of getting TESTA TESTA TESTA TESTB TESTC TESTC, i only get TESTA TESTA TESTA. It just gets the first value of multiple which is 3. It disregards the other values after (1, 2).

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you are asking for, but I guess you're asking the question about multidimensional arrays traversal.

this is the code for example, maybe can help you:

```
    int[][] arr = {{23, 45, 123}, {545}, {124,543}};

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("-------" + i + "-------");
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
```